# Variable table row span echoing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to echo a table in PHP wherein list of appointments is showing like this.

```
-----------------------------------
Date   | Company   | Executive Name  
-----------------------------------
01     | Comapany1 | Mr. XX1
-----------------------------------
01     | Comapany2 | Mr. XX2
-----------------------------------
02     | Comapany3 | Mr. XX3
-----------------------------------
02     | Comapany4 | Mr. XX4
-----------------------------------
02     | Comapany5 | Mr. XX5
-----------------------------------
03     | Comapany6 | Mr. XX6
-----------------------------------
```

But I want to echo like this....... here the rowspan is variable. Because the number of appointments vary by date:

```
-----------------------------------
Date   | Company   | Executive Name  
-----------------------------------
01     | Comapany1 | Mr. XX1
        ----------------------------
       | Comapany2 | Mr. XX2
-----------------------------------
       | Comapany3 | Mr. XX3
       ----------------------------
02     | Comapany4 | Mr. XX4
       ----------------------------
       | Comapany5 | Mr. XX5
-----------------------------------
03     | Comapany6 | Mr. XX6
-----------------------------------
```

How can I accomplish this......Below is my current code

```
      while(($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo"<td width=15%>" . $app_date."</td>";
      echo"<td align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $result['company'] . "</td>";
      echo"<td align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $result['exe_name'] . "</td>";
      echo"<td>" . $result['mobile'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: $app_date ???? what is this?

Comment: it is the appointment date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fully working code:

```
$groupedRows = array();

$results = array(array('app_date' => '2012-03-01', 'company' => 'abc' , 'exe_name' => 'lol'),
array('app_date' =>  '2012-03-01', 'company' => 'def' , 'exe_name' => 'lol2'),
array('app_date' =>  '2012-03-03', 'company' => 'lololololol' , 'exe_name' => 'lol4')
);
foreach ($results as $result) {
 $groupBy = $result['app_date']; // this is simbolic - i don't know where do you get it from;
     $groupedRows[$groupBy][] = array(
          'company' => $result['company'], 'exe_name' => $result['exe_name']
     );
 }

$displayed = array();
foreach ($groupedRows as $groupedBy => $group) {
$rowSpan = count($group);

foreach ($group as $result) {
echo "<tr>";
if (empty($displayed[$groupedBy])){
$displayed[$groupedBy] = true;
echo"<td rowspan='".$rowSpan."' width=15%>" . $groupedBy."</td>";
}
echo"<td align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $result['company'] . "</td>";
echo"<td align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;" . $result['exe_name'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $result['mobile'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

Comment: Mr.TK in the 2nd set of codes $groupedby doesnt echo dates

Comment: Please review the code i have writen and you gave us once again. $app_date is null - not setted. In your code it's not setted as well. Thats your job to do it. Does my answer helps you print the table as you wished? If yes please accept it.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Do you still have a problem with setting $app_date ?

Comment: There was  no problem with app_date.., bcz my first table echoing properly

Comment: Oh - i'm sorry - i see my mistake now :) Let me change the code for you

Comment: Can you unaccept the answer? I cannot edit accepted :) If no i will answer in comments :)

Comment: Change my displaying code first three lines into this:

    foreach ($groupedRows as $groupedBy => $group) {
       $rowSpan = count($group);
           foreach ($group as  $result) {

Comment: Still cannot edit ;) Hope some moderator will do that for me :) Reaccept the answer please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48703/discussion-between-mr-tk-and-indra)

Comment: Sorry for this mess :) The Avast Antivirus addon blocked the edit link. ;) My current answer shell work as You wished Indra.